# Laravel don't seed extended models

Tags: php, laravel

I create alternative Id filed called alterId in database and use it in some cases instead of id field.

For example, on edit data client send alterId value instead of id...

Because it's part of a code that often repeats itself I extended Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model class with this class:

```
namespace App\NewModel;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class NewModel extends Model
{           
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->attributes['alterId'] = $this->generateAlterId();
    }

    public static function convertIdToAlterId($alterId)
    {   
        // some logic to convert if to alterId
    }

    public static function convertAlterIdToId($id)
    {
        // some logic to alterId to id
    }   

    public function generateAlterId($tokenSize = 32)
    {
        // logic to generate alter id ftom time stamp or something like that...
    }

}
```

that generate alterId automatically and has possibility of converting from one to the other.

My problem is when I try to seed some element with this extended model nothing happens, no errors and no inserted data in database.

For seeding I use this model

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

use \App\NewModel;

class TestModel extends NewModel
{
    protected $fillable = ['name']; 

    protected $dates = ['created_at', 'updated_at'];

}
```

this simple factory:

```
use Faker\Generator as Faker;

$factory->define(App\TestModel::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'name' => $faker->firstNameMale,
        'created_at' => \Carbon\Carbon::now(), 
        'updated_at' => \Carbon\Carbon::now()
    ];
});
```

and seeder:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

use \App\TestModel;

class TestModelsTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        //truncate
        TestModel::truncate();

        //create
        factory(TestModel::class, 100)->create();
    }
}
```

As I said before, nothing happens when I start the command

```
php artisan migrate:refresh --seed
```

even a error not showed. But if I change code and modify TestModel to inherits the Model instead of the NewModel then everything works fine, database get inserts!

What did I do wrong in this code?

Comment: Can you show the model? Is it listed as fillable?

Comment: Model is TestModel and has just name. Did you mean that?

Comment: define those functions in the 'TestModel' instead of in another model.

Comment: This is reason why I extend model class. I have over 50 models, and if I create those functions in models  have to repeat these code in each model.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried to run your code, but I think you need to make it fillable:

```
protected $fillable = ['name','alterId'];
```